How did English end up with a voiced "z" at the end of words?
How did English end up with a voiced "z" at the end of words, for example in "is", "was", "those"? Does this phenomenon exist in any Indio-European language other than English?

Bonus question: When native French speakers attempt to speak German, do they have a tendency to voice the ending "s"? If they do, this would explain this feature in English.

When the letter ‘s’ is after a vowel, another ‘s’, or a voiced consonant,
it is pronounced as a /z/ sound.
e.g., logs, tubes, beds, moves, clothes, was, becomes, he’s, passes. So. Mostly, it's plural. As opposed to unvoiced. So, the quesiton is: Why is /z/ a plural in English?

https://www.antidote.info/en/blog/reports/the-norse-epic-of-the-english-plural-s For both voiced and unvoiced ones, plus the irregulars that are still around.

Yes, it exists in other Indo-European languages.
For example, in the French word française.
It also exists in some other Romance languages like Romanian, in Serbo-Croatian and Ukrainian, in Armenian and Persian.
It may be a bit odd for a Germanic language, though it is found in Yiddish, e.g. frukhtloz,frukhtayz… (cf. modern formal German fruchtlos. Fruchteis).  Basically in continental West German, it ended up that in Southern German it’s always s, in Yiddish it’s always z, and in the modern Northern pronunciation of standard German it is z but devoiced to s if not followed by a vowel.
It is not found in Spanish, Portuguese, standard Italian or Russian or some other Slavic languages, even though the words are spellt with -z.
Not sure about Greek, Baltic or Indic languages.  My sense is that Greek or Indic languages have it in loans like “jazz” or “khuda hafez”, but not sure if it occurs in core native words and morphological endings like it does in English.

So presumably, this feature came from French/Norman?

@MWB Unlikely, since many of the words where it’s found in English now are inherited English words, not French loans. Intervocalic fricatives were voiced in quite a few contexts in English (that’s also why we have noun/verb or singular/plural pairs like breath/breathe, knife/knives, etc.). Final /z/ is also reconstructed for Proto-Germanic, but was later lost outside English, either by (a) developing into /r/ (in Norse), or (b) becoming /s/ through final devoicing (West Germanic except English).

@JanusBahsJacquet It seems it is found in Yiddish, which is West Germanic.

@JanusBahsJacquet / Adam: Do you happen to know if Dutch, Frisian or Danish have this feature?

@MWB Dutch – and I believe also Frisian – has final devoicing, so /z/ cannot appear at the end of words (e.g., huis ‘house’, pl. huizen), and Danish has no voiced obstruents (and thus no /z/) at all.

@Adam True, but if Wikipedia is anything to go by, that is a later reversal in Eastern Yiddish, possibly by Slavic influence (cf. gut tak in the oldest known Yiddish text, written with qof instead of gimel as gut tag). I don’t know nearly enough about Yiddish to know if the devoicing is present in words where the final obstruent was never part of a final/non-final pair and thus would have no analogical counterpart to be re-voiced by.

Might be a candidate? https://fa.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%BA%D8%A7%D8%B2

@AdamBittlingmayer. Persian has lots of (non-borrowed) words ending in -z, mostly the reflex of Indo-Iranian post-vocalic -č.

Pretty sure loans like jazz are indeed the only places where non-final /z/ appears in Greek.

While most Slavic languages have final devoicing for most obstruents, Serbo-Croatian and Ukrainian do not, so their ⟨-z⟩ / ⟨-з⟩ is [z̪].

In Russian whether the -z is de-voiced depends on the next word, so it is wrong to ay that Russian does not have word-final -z.

@Anixx, I would say that progressive voicedness assimilation across word-boundaries in Russian is a separate process from the word-final devoicing. You say арбуз in isolation and it will sound like арбус. And I am so very confident that Russian definitely has no sentence-final -z.

@OmarandLorraine word-final -z is allophonic with -s in case of de-voicing, so it is individual specifics to what extent and where people de-voice it. Definitely, in case of ambiguity less people de-voice consonants to underline the meaining.

@OmarandLorraine voicing assimilation does not happen when the final consonant is underlyingly non-voiced. In that case it remains de-voiced in any case.

@JanusBahsJacquet, You said "Final /z/ is also reconstructed for Proto-Germanic, but was later lost [...] by [...] developing into /r/ (in Norse)" I was under the impression this happened in English as well, hence the alternations "was/were", "is/are". Do you know anything about this?

@OmarandLorraine That’s intervocalic position, not final. Since it was eventually lost finally anyway (after unaccented syllables, not in monosyllabics), I’m not sure offhand if it’s possible to categorically say that it didn’t first pass through a rhotacised stage in West Germanic as well, but it’s not necessary.

française The audio version for France definitely sounds like it ends in a vowel (despite the IPA) And the Quebec version kind of sounds like it's almost devoiced to me.

@MWB French schwa is unstable – in normal speech, it’s usually absent in word-final position, but in careful speech, it’s often present. The recording on Wiktionary definitely says [fʁɑ̃sɛːzə], pronouncing it, but [fʁɑ̃sɛːz] is equally possible, just like both [sεtə] and [sεt] are possible for cette ‘this (f.)’ or even sept ‘seven’. It’s generally, I believe, held to be a non-phonemic, epenthetic vowel in word-final position (cf. this paper).

@JanusBahsJacquet i always hought the final -z i française is not pronouned, at least, in Russian there are idioms with this French word without final -z

@Anixx The final s is usually dropped in the masculine form of the word – français. However, in française – the feminine form – the s is always sounded (as /z/) and sometimes the e is too (as explained by Janus above).

@Segorian thanks, this clarifies!

@Arfrever You’re right, in Serbo-Croatian it’s kind of there.  I should know this - my family is from there, but I’m from an ethnic minority that has no z at all (Swabian) and I use other Slavic languages much more these days.  For those who are interested: https://youtu.be/W4LUCE7suIQ?si=5-9S7kv2Wb48xEV_

@fdb Yes, native Persian is full of it.  My question about borrowings pertains only to Indic, because the Indic words with -z that I can think if are all borrowings, mainly from Persian in fact.

@MWB The version of française with the final -ə is a bit affected.
